# Need help to make trigger and VP

Tags: visualforce, trigger, custom-object, custom-field, field-update

1.- Create an object called A, with a date field called DateA
- Create an object called B, with a lookup field to A and a date field called DateB

2.- Create a trigger that will set the DateA field as the highest of the children's DateB field

3.- Create a VF page that will receive the id of an A object and will allow you to mass edit the DateB fields on the child B objects, in a table .

I have done the 1.st point, I have created an object called A with a date field called DateA and I have created another object called B with a lookup field to A and a date field called DateB.
I learn triggers from youtube but this is something which I dont find anywhere,so I have difficulty at the 2nd and the 3rd point.
Any suggestion or help would be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

for #2, why have a trigger?
If you only want the highest date from your child records - you can use a rollup summary field. 
You can take the "MAX" option returning for the date field you want which will give you the highest date among all the child records.